# How to swap two variables using bitwise operators (not XOR, and without temporary var)

Tags: java

How to swap two variables using bitwise operators (not XOR, and without temporary var). I need to swap two variables by two ways, one way is XOR as demonstrated below:

```java
int x = 10;
int y = 22;
x = x ^ y;
y = y ^ x;  // y is now 10
x = x ^ y;  // x is now 22
```

Comment: Tried anything so far ?

Comment: What type of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XOR, `p ^ q`, can be expressed using the and (`&`), or (`|`), and not/invert (`~`) bitwise operators as `(p & q) | ~(p & q)` (see Wikipedia's [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) article). Hence, we can now simulate an XOR with the other bitwise operators to do the usual swap.

```java
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
x = (x & y) | ~(x & y);
y = (y & x) | ~(y & x);
x = (x & y) | ~(x & y);
```

Although note Java will create temporary variables to store the intermediate values in the expression (eg. the results of `x & y`), so in practice or on real architectures this is slower than just storing a variable in a temporary, but from a theory perspective it may satisfy your question.

Note that @ytoamn's answer is a better solution than mine as the JVM wouldn't need to create extra temporary variables to store intermediate parts of expressions. (And isn't just an XOR workaround)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for

Comment: @ytoamn's no problem, although answer is probably better unless you want to imitate XOR with temporaries :)

Comment: Yes, but he answer on his own question, not mine, and did not show me anything new

Comment: Ide says - "Operator '!' cannot be applied to 'int'"

Comment: Ah, it's the `~` operator I should have used. Oops, will fix answer.

Answer (score 2):

1 way is using a third variable, the other is using addition and subtraction

```
a = 10, b = 7

a = a - b ; // a = 3
b = b + a ; // b = 10
a = b - a ; // a = 7
```