# (Java) Swapping variables, which method is quickest and uses the least memory?

Tags: java

Suppose I wanna swap variables with eachother. Which of the solutions below would be the faster and requires less memory? **Note:** there is only 2 variables to be swapped here, but imagined we had one billion variables to be swapped.

**Solution 1:**

```
public class Exc15 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int c = 1;
        int d = 2;
        int e = c;
        System.out.println(c + " " + d);
        c = d;
        d = e;
        System.out.println(c + " " + d);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;                
        System.out.println(a + " " + b);
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
        System.out.println(a + " " + b);
        } 
}
```

Comment: I dont see any swapping being done here.

Comment: Use bitwise. Solution 2 may give wrong result due to overflow. Already asked many times. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440742/how-to-swap-two-variables-using-bitwise-operators-not-xor-and-without-temporar)

Comment: It's not quite clear what swapping a billion variables means; which swaps with which?

Comment: @vinS, overflow is not a problem here, + and - are just fine.. Otherwise, OP, do a simple benchmark and measure the difference. In theory, solution 1 uses less cpu and more stack memory, but in practice, the JIT compiler does some optimization and it's unclear which would perform better.

Comment: @xs0 I was going to benchmark it, but the operations are so few in this case that the result probably will be in nanoseconds and not accurate, im a beginner and don't know how to add many variables quickly, e.g. one million, to make a bigger test with time results in seconds and not in nanoseconds. According to your answer i will just use Solution 1 in the future, thanks!

Comment: First way is probably faster because it's five assignments and no additions/subtractions;   second way is also five assignments, but with  three additions/subtractions.  It's a push on memory consumption: First way uses three named `int` variables and occupies one stack slot momentarily during each assignment; second way uses only two named variables but momentarily occupies  two stack positions during each add/subtract.

Comment: @Someguy3567 just run it a billion times in a loop or whatever, there's no need to measure just one execution..

Comment: @Kevin Anderson, thanks, that was a nice answer!